# Can I Change Definition of a importet module with my own DEF?

Tags: python, function, pyautogui

Letz Say i import Pyautogui (i have a script were its import pyautogui like this)

```
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
```

Then the creator changes click
so:

```
def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
    time.sleep(0.1) #This pauses the script for 0.1 seconds
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)
```

that overwrites the normal function of click from pyautogui right?? but if i use pyautogui.click it is not my def right??

i want to change pyautogui.click and def click to this

```
    pyautogui.moveTo((x,y), random.uniform(0.5, 2.7), pyautogui.easeInBounce)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
    time.sleep(0.1) #This pauses the script for 0.1 seconds
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)
```

maybe i can change it completele to pyautogui?? i dont know why the creator of the script is using win32api instead of pyautogui

so when i make def like

```
def pyautogui.moveTo((x,y))
pyautogui.moveTo((x,y), random.uniform(0.5, 2.7), pyautogui.easeInBounce)
```

is that working??? maybe not or ?

i want to change pyautogui.click and def click to this

```
    pyautogui.moveTo((x,y), random.uniform(0.5, 2.7), pyautogui.easeInBounce)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
    time.sleep(0.1) #This pauses the script for 0.1 seconds
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)
```

maybe i can change it completele to pyautogui?? i dont know why the creator of the script is using win32api instead of pyautogui

so when i make def like

```
def pyautogui.moveTo((x,y))
pyautogui.moveTo((x,y), random.uniform(0.5, 2.7), pyautogui.easeInBounce)
```

`

Comment: Please review and edit your post to fix formatting and remove repetitive parts. And no, you can't write `def pyautogui.moveTo`. Don't ask us "is that working", try it yourself and tell us the result. And please see [ask]

Comment: sorry hard to me for understanding i try to change the formation. also too change pyautogui.moveTo i have to make a new def with oother name and use the moveto function inside and use then the def name right inside the code.